# roscpp dependency error

Tags: ros-melodic, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Platform: ROS Melodic on Debian Stretch IDE: QtCreator

Hello,

I strictly followed installation guide and package creating tutorial on a fresh install of Debian Stretch for Ros Melodic to install my environment. Then I created a package using `catkin_create_pkg` in a workspace that is tested to be valid. Then I followed IDE's wiki page steps to write a piece of C++ code to try if it is working but I got a roscpp dependency error from CMAKE `Could not find a package configuration file provided by "roscpp" with any of the following names:`

Afterwards I tried to do it with catkin tools on a separate workspace using catkin create pkg and followed the steps for it again but still the same error.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
 project(pkg_a)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
)

include_directories(
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
```

I have three lines in my .bashrc file for sourcing the packages.

`source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash`
`source /home/<username>/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`
`source /home/<username>/pkg_ws/devel/setup.bash`
#The last line added later on after trying to find a way with catkin tools

Links to the guides I followed

Installation: http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Debian

To setup the environment: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment

To build packages with catkin_make: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages

IDE setup: http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs

Output of `env | grep -i ros | sort`

```
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/<username>/pkg_ws/devel:/home/<username>/catkin_ws/devel:/opt/ros/melodic
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/<username>/pkg_ws/devel/lib:/home/<username>/catkin_ws/devel/lib:/opt/ros/melodic/lib
PATH=/opt/ros/melodic/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/<username>/pkg_ws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/home/<username>/catkin_ws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/melodic/lib/pkgconfig
PYTHONPATH=/home/<username>/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
ROS_DISTRO=melodic
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/melodic/etc/ros
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/<username>/pkg_ws/devel/share/common-lisp:/home/<username>/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/<username>/pkg_ws/src/pkg_a:/home/<username>/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/melodic/share
ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=2
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS_VERSION=1
```

rospack find roscpp

```
/opt/ros/melodic/share/roscpp
```

@Solved

If anybody has the same issue; I made it work through making the changes to QtCreator in the IDEs wiki page section 3. catkin tools but made it run through the 2. method (catkin_make)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331559/roscpp-dependency-error/) by [Adam](https://answers.ros.org/users/45164/adam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2019-08-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-26**:\

> I strictly followed installation guide and package creating tutorial on a fresh install of Debian Stretch for Ros Melodic to install my environment.

Please always link to any tutorials/guides/howtos/documentation you are using.

We don't always know what you refer to.

---

Edit: also add the output of `env | grep -i ros | sort` and `rospack find roscpp` to your question text. Use the `edit` button/link for that.

**Comment by [prefpkg21](https://answers.ros.org/users/40119/prefpkg21/) on 2019-08-26**:
which directory did you run catkin_create_pkg? Also, is that your entire CMakelists file? I didn't see where you declared your cpp executable or linked the catkin libraries

**Comment by [Adam](https://answers.ros.org/users/45164/adam/) on 2019-08-26**:
@prefpkg21

Managed to run CMake succesfully after creating a package using catkin tools but this time ros.h file couldn't be found.

**Comment by [prefpkg21](https://answers.ros.org/users/40119/prefpkg21/) on 2019-08-26**:
does the CMakelists portion of your original post reflect the current file in your package?

**Comment by [Adam](https://answers.ros.org/users/45164/adam/) on 2019-08-26**:
@prefpkg21

Actually yes, but the package created with catkin_create_pkg started working now. Thank you for the help

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-26**:
Please post your last edit as an answer and then accept your own answer.

**Comment by [Adam](https://answers.ros.org/users/45164/adam/) on 2019-08-27**:
@gvdhoorn
Sorry I couldn't accept my answer because I dont have enough points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If anybody has the same issue; I made it work through making the changes to QtCreator in the IDEs wiki page section 3. catkin tools but made it run through the 2. method (catkin_make)

---

Originally posted by [Adam](https://answers.ros.org/users/45164/adam/) with karma: 18 on 2019-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0